# receive on action all object with checkbox checked, rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am making a system private message.

I want catch all object with checkbox checked and if the user click on trash, send to trash action and if click on spam, send to spam action inside message controller. You can see the next image:

[image]

This is my checkbox html :

```
<input class="check" id="506c82001d41c82198000056" name="506c82001d41c82198000056" type="checkbox" value="506c82001d41c82198000056">
```

Is generated with:

```
<%= check_box_tag m.id, m.id, false, :class => "check" %>
```

Delete and spam button are links with format:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", delete_message_path %>
<%= link_to "Spam", spam_message_path %>
```

**how I can send the results that have been marked with checkbox checkeck to each action?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure html implementation, you can route the form to a single controller action and either handle delete and spam logic from there or redirect to those actions.

In your form

```
<%= form_tag('/messages_cleanup', method: :put) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Spam" %>

  <%= message.each do |m| %>
    <%= check_box_tag m.id, m.id, false, :class => "check" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

you can have two submit tags that lead to some url, say `/messages_cleanup` which has a route like `match /messages_cleanup, :to => 'messages#cleanup'`.

Then in your messages controller, you can check the submit type in the `params[:commit]` field.

```
def cleanup
  case params[:commit]
    when "Delete"
      # either handle delete logic here or redirect to delete path
    when "Spam"
      # either handle spam logic here or redirect to spam path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible make with `link_to` instead `form_for`?. I use simple_form gem...

Comment: It should be possible to do this with `simple_form`. Why do you want to use `link_to`?

Comment: I use twitter bootstrap framework http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons. The buttons are with `<button>` and `<a href="">` tags instead input... I will try with this way :D. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to reuse these styles with `input` tags.